# Android TextView doesn't resize after changing text size

Tags: java, android, textview, font-size

I have a `ListView` with some custom layout for the row (an image, then two lines of text using two `TextView` in a vertical `LinearLayout`, see code below)

My problem is that when I dynamically change the text size (in the `getView` method of the `Adapter`), the text size does change, but the size of the `TextView` that wraps it doesn't.

Here is a picture of what it does when I set the size to something "higher" than the default (picture is with 18). Despite the large number of threads or questions that seem similar, I haven't found a solution to that.

[image: screen capture]

Here is the layout of my list row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/entries_list_item_icon"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="6dp"/>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="0dip"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/entries_list_item_name"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:textColor="@color/entries_list_item_name"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/entries_list_item_summary"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:ellipsize="marquee"
              android:textColor="@color/entries_list_item_summary"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried switching the heights to `0dip` as suggested elsewhere, it didn't change a thing.

**EDIT** The `ListView` itself is very basic:

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/entries_list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your `height` attributes to `wrap_content`

Comment: The only one that's not at wrap_content is the vertical LinearLayout, all the other ones already are. And yes, I did try changing this one too (I just tried again), no change - the LinearLayout wraps around the two TextView, but each of the TextView has an incorrect size already...

Comment: Sorry I meant `width` attribute! But now I'm seeing that's probably not your problem.

Comment: No, I'm fine with the width being "too wide for the screen", I just want the height of the TextViews (and the whole List item) to be modified as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to change `imageview` height to `fill_parent`. Imageview is dictating the height of your layout.

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/entries_list_item_icon"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />
```

Comment: It works! Wow, thanks a ton. How come the ImageView height dictates the whole layout? Is it because it's the first one on the LinearLayout?

Comment: 25 minutes to get a solution. I love StackOverflow ;)

Comment: i myself am not sure, but seeing your image it looked like the layout height was being restricted to image hieght