# Resizing the textview size based on the screen width for all devices

Tags: android, textview

I have problem in resizing the text view .

I have a Layout like this with below components

ImageView| TextView | ImageView

placed in `relativelayout(horizontal)` and each one width is wrap content and height is fill parent.

**PROBLEM**

I have a text like this `"My name","My name is xyzmnop"` now, i have fixed the `TextView` size to 15sp, so what is happening is in larger devices since Textviews width increases the text "My name is xyzmnop" will fit but in smaller devices since the width is small it will spill out to second line. But i want it to be in *same line*, as I have the flexibility to decrease the size of the text if the text is lengthy.

please help me with this problem.

i have seen this

- [Android TextView doesn't resize after changing text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774431/android-textview-doesnt-resize-after-changing-text-size)
- [Android EditText Resize Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492725/android-edittext-resize-programatically)
- [Resizing TextView does not shrink its height on Android 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986384/resizing-textview-does-not-shrink-its-height-on-android-3-1)

EDIT:

I have also added setSingleLine = "true"; in my xml

Comment: What is your actual question? As the answers below seem to answer the question you posted... (but are not the answer you seem to desire)

Answer (score 1):

Say, `tv` is your TextView.

Just call `tv.setMaxLines(1);`

Comment: no thats not the point i want the textview to be in single line and i have added that in xml, problem is  with the test size

Comment: Downvoting won't get you an answer sooner. Anyway, you're clearly asking how to make a TextView text show in just one line, and that's what we provided. Maybe you wanted other thing, if you want the answers, learn to make the questions.

Comment: Also, maybe you will want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` has the [`setMaxLines (int maxlines)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29) method:

> Makes the TextView at most this many lines tall. Setting this value overrides any other (maximum) height setting.

I suppose this might help you if you set the maximum number of lines to 1.

Note: there is also the [`android:maxlines`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3amaxLines) attribute if you need to set it in your XML layout.

Answer (score -1):

i have solved it using ViewTreeObserver.

Comment: can u please explain how did you achieve this? I am also facing the same problem

Comment: look at the example of ViewTreeObserver. you will get the answer